# What is the importance of uniqueness theorem of a limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

Almost in every calculus book the uniqueness theorem of a limit is the first theorem. Which can be stated as follows

> If $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=L_1$ and $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=L_2$, then $L_1=L_2$.

What is the importance of this theorem?

Comment: How would you find discontinuities without unique limits? How would you define continuity without unique limits?

Comment: How would you use the phrase "the limit?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that theorem were false, then you couldn't coherently talk about limits at all, and analysis would look very, very different. This is one of the many theorems of the form "the thing which has to be true is, in fact, true".

Answer (score 4):

Before you have proved that limits are unique, even writing “$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$” is meaningless.

To be pedantic, one should first define what “$f(x)\to L$ as $x \to a$” means, and then formulate the theorem as follows:

> If $f(x)\to L_1$ as $x \to a$ and $f(x)\to L_2$ as $x \to a$, then $L_1=L_2$.

Once you know this (but not before), it makes sense to introduce $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ as notation for the *unique* number $L$ such that $f(x) \to L$ as $x \to a$.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by the others, the theorem is very fundamental!
Especially because it is just true for the setting you have, I assume $f$ is a map between metrical spaces?

For metrical spaces or more structured space, the limit is unique and everything works fine. But you can define continuity and convergence for sequences even for topological spaces and in topological spaces, a limit has not to be unique! And then a lot of arguments don't work anymore.